# Limiting items in one drop-down based on selection in another drop-down

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, telerik

I have two drop-downs A and B. Based on what I select in drop-down A, I want to limit the items shown in B. Is there a property I can bind in xaml or is there any other way to achieve it? I'm using VS 2012, WPF, MVVM model and telerik controls.

Comment: What do you mean by limit the items? Have you tried any code? This question is too vauge to answer.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you’ve written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: @PierreLebon Reading through my post again does make it seem like that and I should have provided some code, though I was looking for guidance in handling the scenario in xaml and viewmodel. The negative marking doesn't seem very justified to me, but I've gone through the links you provided and thanks for your feedback anyways.

Comment: @Simsons Sorry, my question does seem a little vague.By limiting the items I meant that the items populated in the second dropdown will depend on the item I select in the first dropdown. But I've managed it so thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us consider the example of Country and State combo box where state combo box will be populated according to the selection on the Country combo box.

So, If I speak in terms of XAML properties, here you want to update ItemsSource property of State combo box on basis of SelectedItem property of Country combo box.

To achieve this, add a new property "SelectedCountry" in ViewModel which will hold the selection of Country combo box. In Setter of this "SelectedCountry" property, set StateCollection as per your need.

Make sure to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface and use ObservableCollection type for both the collections.

Following is the code sample for the same:

> Model Classes:

```
public class Country
{
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public List<State> States { get; set; }
}

public class State
{
    public string StateName { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }
}
```

> ViewModel :

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        CountriesCollection = new ObservableCollection<Country>();
        StateCollection = new ObservableCollection<State>();
        LoadData();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Country> _CountriesCollection;

    public ObservableCollection<Country> CountriesCollection
    {
        get { return _CountriesCollection; }
        set
        {
            _CountriesCollection = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CountriesCollection");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<State> _StatesCollection;

    public ObservableCollection<State> StateCollection
    {
        get { return _StatesCollection; }
        set
        {
            _StatesCollection = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("StateCollection");
        }
    }

    private Country _SelectedCountry;

    public Country SelectedCountry
    {
        get { return _SelectedCountry; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedCountry = value;
            if (_SelectedCountry != null && _SelectedCountry.States != null)
            {
                StateCollection = new ObservableCollection<State>(_SelectedCountry.States);
            }
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedCountry");
        }
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        if (CountriesCollection != null)
        {
            CountriesCollection.Add(new Country
            {
                CountryId = 1,
                CountryName = "India",
                States = new List<State>
                            {
                                    new State { StateId = 1, StateName = "Gujarat"},
                                    new State { StateId = 2, StateName = "Punjab"},
                                    new State { StateId = 3, StateName = "Maharastra"}
                            }
            });
            CountriesCollection.Add(new Country
            {
                CountryId = 2,
                CountryName = "Chine",
                States = new List<State>
                            {
                                    new State { StateId = 4, StateName = "Chine_State1"},
                                    new State { StateId = 5, StateName = "Chine_State2"},
                                    new State { StateId = 6, StateName = "Chine_State3"}
                            }
            });
            CountriesCollection.Add(new Country
            {
                CountryId = 3,
                CountryName = "japan",
                States = new List<State>
                            {
                                    new State { StateId = 7, StateName = "Japan_State1"},
                                    new State { StateId = 8, StateName = "Japan_State2"},
                                    new State { StateId = 9, StateName = "Japan_State3"}
                            }
            });
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }

}
```

> XALM :

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <ComboBox 
              Height="30" Width="100" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding CountriesCollection}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCountry}"
              DisplayMemberPath="CountryName">
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox
              Height="30" Width="100" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30"  
              ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedCountry.States}"
              DisplayMemberPath="StateName">
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

> XAML.CS

```
InitializeComponent();
this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
```

I hope this example will make things clear for you. Let me know if you need any more information on this.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and example code. Although I've already managed to implement it and went through your answer only now, I've implemented it in an almost similar manner as your solution with only a few changes (like I've used RaisePropertyChanged instead of NotifyPropertyChanged in the setter and since I'm supposed to fetch data for the dropdown from the database, I decided to implement the logic for it in the procedure). You've clarified a couple more things for me with your code, thanks again :)

Comment: @VandanaChandola Glad that my answer helped you anyway! please upvote it and mark it as answer if my post answered your question so that this could be useful for other fellows in future as well.

Comment: Already tried upvoting your answer, but since my reputation is less than 15, it won't show.

Comment: Yes the grey tick. Done :)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to have both list exist in the viewmodel, plus two properties to hold the selected item(data item).

Have the two ComboBox binded to those properties, and in the viewmodel handle the 'FirstSelectedItem' property changed(or entry to its setter).

That way you can modify the the members of the second list.

Comment: Yes thank you for your input, I've implemented it similarly :) In the setter of the second dropdown I've called a function that provides the selected item of the first dropdown as parameter to a procedure where the rest of the logic is implemented. That does the job for me, thanks again :)